# Adding Associated Domains Entitlement For a Flutter App

Tags: ios, xcode, android-studio, flutter, associated-domains

I need to add Associated Domains Entitlement to my Flutter app, so I can implement *App Links*.
I use the [uni_links](https://github.com/avioli/uni_links/issues/47) plugin which works well for Android. I've added a `ios/Runner/Runner.entitlements` file as described, but it doesn't work. [Apple official docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/security/password_autofill/setting_up_an_app_s_associated_domains) imply that I need to add something to the app via xcode. Problem is, I don't use xcode, rather Android Studio. I believe I need to manually add an entry to `info.plist` or `project.pbxproj` which is what I believe xcode does, however I am not sure what.

Answer (score 19):

Open the Runner.entitlements file from this path :

```
ios/Runner/Runner.entitlements
```

And add the applink you want

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
  <!-- ... other keys -->
  <key>com.apple.developer.associated-domains</key>
  <array>
    <string>applinks:[YOUR_HOST]</string>
  </array>
  <!-- ... other keys -->
</dict>
</plist>
```

For more information, read Apple's guide for [Universal Links](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Conceptual/AppSearch/UniversalLinks.html).

Comment: did that and it doesn't work (on simulator). my question was if i need to do something *additional* in xcode

Comment: In Xcode, go to `Capabilites`, in that section there is an option to add Associated Domains. First switch it on and then add the link as applinks. Applinks and webcredentials are different:

applinks is for universal links

webcredentials is for web credential sharing .   is this answer your question @shaharsol

Comment: I believe this stuff doesn't work in the Simulator at all and needs testing on a real device. Also, since it hasn't been mentioned explicitly, you also need to create matching settings on your web domain for Apple to scrape.

Comment: @MartinWestin yes ita it doesnt work in simulator plus it is a pre-requisite to have aasa file uploaded on the web domain for Universal link or app links to work.

Answer (score 1):

Log in to [Apple Developer Account](https://developer.apple.com/). 
Check your bundle Id. Edit your App ID. Add **Associated Domain** Entitlement from there. Update Provisioning profile and Use it in your Flutter project.

Comment: It means you need to select your app Id and Edit Capabilities from there.